# I created a WordPress website, it was working fine, but suddenly it stops displaying everything on server? How can I resolve the issue?

Tags: wordpress

I created a WordPress website,
 it was working fine, but suddenly it 
stops displaying everything on server? 
How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: provide site url

Answer (score 0):

Go to **root/wp-config.php** and find `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` then change `false` to `true` and refresh your website page. if you couldn't see any errors, then check your server **error.log**

Answer (score 0):

The steps for checking errors

**Step 1** check your error_log file in your root directory

**Step 2** go to your wp-config.php and enable the define('WP_DEBUG', true);

**Step 3** check your database connections username , password or database name.

**Step 4** check plugins directory is there any plugins which is going to conflict with others or with your website.

**Step 5** open your firebug and click to consol tab check is there any errors related to javascript.

**Step 6** check your website and wp-admin url in wp_options table from database.

**step 7** resloved your errors if there anyone into your error_blog files or debug mode

thanks

Answer (score 0):

check your current theme's functions.php file is having proper code or not in some cases when website hack this file gets empty and site not working. so this might be case.

also check file permission of functions.php.